# NPM install gives error fatal: reference is not a tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

I am trying to build my JavaScript files with Grunt. but when I run npm install, it shows me error message "fatal: reference is not a tree:cef34f39dcfwe(commit Id i guess).

Anyone has idea?

Thanks

Comment: You should post a `package.json` that people can try to install.

Answer (score 4):

Remove **package-lock.json** and run `npm install`
if it didn't work try this:

`npm update` then  `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Delete all references to that package from node module for which you are getting this issue then try clearing node modules by using

```
npm cache clear --force
```

then use

```
npm install
```